# Statement requires expression of integer type ('NSArray* __ strong' invalid)

Tags: xcode, integer, nsarray, switch-statement

below is part 1 of the code

```
menuItems = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"page 1",@"page 2",@"page 3",@"page 4",@"page 5",@"page 6",@"page 7", nil];
for (int b=0;b<[menuItems count];b++) {
    UIButton *mybutton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3.0f, originofButtons, buttonWidth, buttonHeight)];
    mybutton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [mybutton setTag:b];
    [mybutton setTitle:[menuItems objectAtIndex:b] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [mybutton setSelected:false];
    [mybutton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonpress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [m_scrollview addSubview:mybutton];

    originofButtons += (buttonHeight + buttonseparator);

}
```

below is the switch method i want to implement for the code above

```
- (void)m_scrollview:(UIScrollView *)m_scrollview clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSArray*)buttonpress
{

switch (buttonpress)
{
case 0:
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"about" sender:self];
    break;
case 1:
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"about" sender:self];
    break;
case 2:
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"about" sender:self];
    break;
case 3:
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"about" sender:self];
    break;
case 4:
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"about" sender:self];
    break;

}  
}
```

i cant get it to switch. the code below is technically correct because xcode shows no errors. but it wont run. xcode will then give me error:

[MainViewController buttonpress:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb5385c1c40 2014-12-13 23:09:37.705 APP[13563:14150802] * Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MainViewController buttonpress:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb5385c1c40' * First throw call stack:

if i use the code below i can get it to work. and all @1,2,3,4 5 etc will have the same segue

```
-(void)buttonpress:(id)sender {
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"about" sender:self];
[self drawerAnimation];



}
```

how can i fix this code to be able to use a switch method for all the "@"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an OS X programmer, so the details might be a little different, but basically the answer is in the title to your question.

In the switch statement, buttonpress needs to be an integer.  Also, it's a good idea to make your switch statement exhaustive by including a default action.

```
-(void)buttonpress:(id)sender 
{
    NSInteger senderButton = [sender tag];

    switch (senderButton)
    {
    case 0:
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"about" sender:self];
    break;
    case 1:
      [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"about" sender:self];
    break;
    case 2:
      [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"about" sender:self];
    break;
    case 3:
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"about" sender:self];
    break;
    case 4:
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"about" sender:self];
    break;
    default:
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"about" sender:self];
    break;
    }
}
```

Also I assume that the statement:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"about" sender:self];
```

sends a valid selector.  If not, Xcode will not catch this. This will be a run time error.

Comment: Dude, that was amazing! i've been fighting with it for months. I totally overlooked! i changed my codes like 50 times looking for the answer and it was something so simple.

Comment: And yes. the segue sends a valid selector... thank you